# CSS select last li-element with specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

i have a list

```
<ul>
    <li class="range1">Entry</li>
    <li class="range1">Entry</li>
    <li class="range1">Entry</li>
    <li class="range2">Entry</li>
    <li class="range2">Entry</li>
    <li class="range2">Entry</li>
</ul>
```

Now i want to select the last li with the class "range1". Problem is, that this list is dynamic cause of a sql database output, so i cant work with nth-child.

```
li.range1:last-child
```

doesnt work. I dont want use Javascript so is it possible to just use CSS?

Comment: Pseudo classes select elements (as counter-intuitive as it may sound), not classes of elements. Adding a class to the selector makes it act more like a filter.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. With JS sure.

Comment: Add a class to the last LI of a group while you are outputting that data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply `last-of-type` or `last-child` to a CSS class.

You can either us Javascript or change your HTML a little bit (preferable solution):

```
<ul class="range">
    <li class="range1">Entry</li>
    <li class="range1">Entry</li>
    <li class="range1 range__last">Entry</li>
    <li class="range2">Entry</li>
    <li class="range2">Entry</li>
    <li class="range2 range__last">Entry</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

last-child works only for the last element of its parent irrespective of the class name differentiation that you specify.

alternatively li.range1:nth-child(3) can be used. otherwise it should have  separate container classes for both the lists that u specify

Comment: There's no point in the `.range1` and if the list is dynamic then `:nth-child(3)` isn't going to work.